# could somebody come up with the solution to the following error in react native

Tags: react-native

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.  Check the render method of `SceneComponent'

Comment: const renderScene = SceneMap({
         first:Home,
         second:Best,
         third: New,
     });

Comment: return(
          <TabView
          navigationState={{index,routes}}
          renderScene={renderScene}
          onIndexChange={setIndex}
          initialLayout={initialLayout}
          />

    )
 }

Comment: import React, { useState } from "react";
 import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'

//importing tab view
import {TabView,SceneMap} from 'react-native-tab-view'

//screens importing of tab view

import Home from './Sections/Home'
import Best from './Sections/Best'
import New from './Sections/New'

const initialLayout = {width:Dimensions.get('window').width};

   function HomeScreen()
 {
     const [index, setIndex]=useState(0)
     const [routes]=useState([
         {key:'first', title:'hy'},
         {key:'second', title:'Bist'},
         {key:'third', title:'Njj'},
     ])